# Accidentally made asset folder into "app bundle" how do I undo this??? Xcode

Tags: xcode, bundle, assets

I misclicked an option when I had my assets folder open in Xcode and now the screen where you drag and drop files into app icons etc isn't there, how do I get it back?[When I click on the assets folder all I get is this dropdown menu now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTxUx.png)

Comment: Discard the changes with source control.

Comment: Hi Frankenstein, I tried that and nothing happened. I'm trying to get back to the screen where I can drag & drop my icons + logos manually. Any idea?

Comment: Create a new assets library, then drag the contents of the old folder into the new folder.

Comment: That seemed to have worked, thanks a bunch Warren. I appreciate the help.